# Listening to the contract Events using ethers.js, deployed it on sepolia test network,

Tags: javascript, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I'm not able to listen to the contract events, I'm able to get the data from the contract, but when it comes to listening to the events nothing was printing on the console. with the contract address, I can find this contract on etherscan.

this is the contract
`
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.24;

```
contract EventListener {
uint public a  = 10;
    event SomethingHappened(uint256 num);

    function doSomething(uint _num) public {
        a = _num;
        emit SomethingHappened(_num);
    }
}
```

`

this is the JS code I used to listen to the events

```
    const API_KEY = "";
    const PRIVATE_KEY = '';
    const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x01e80f11F8793B9dD2Bad2041b6244C09D5A2a32";

    const { ethers } = require("ethers");
    const contract = require("../artifacts/contracts/eventListening.sol/EventListener.json");

    // Custom provider for the "sepolia" network // this is 1st private key different then 1st one
    const sepoliaProvider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`https://eth-              sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/tqOelrFoLUoCiFnrf2l8gCRNW9n6lWFb`);

    async function main() {
        // Signer - your Ethereum account
        const signer = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY, sepoliaProvider);
        const contractInstance = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, contract.abi, signer);

        // Listen for the SomethingHappened event once
        await contractInstance.once("SomethingHappened", (num) => {
            console.log(`Event occurred at timestamp: ${num}`);
        });

        // Call your contract function that emits the SomethingHappened event
        await contractInstance.doSomething(80);
    }

    main().then(() => process.exit(0)).catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

the contract was successfully compiled using the hardhat and deployed on the sepolia network

I make the API key and private key as blank for privacy

I want to know where I was getting the mistakes, i tried to go through the some of tutorials but all of them were using already deployed contracts from Etherscan

Comment: can you test `.on` method instead of `.once`. i think for each block .once will be triggered only once. maybe you  already used it